# How can I use Div to format 2 different tables on a page?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to use two or more tables on a page.  My tables were formatted to have alternating rows of different colors.  Actually each cell is a different color but same concept.  I'd like to make a 2nd table and have it use a different set of alternating colors.

The CSS format that works as long as I have a single table is:

```
/* controls 1st cell of ev odd row */
tr:nth-child(odd) td:nth-child(3n+1) {
background-color: rgba(191, 178, 178, 0.44);
color: black;
text-align: center;
}
/* controls 2nd cell of ev odd row */
tr:nth-child(odd) td:nth-child(3n+2) {
background-color: rgba(216, 177, 161, 0.46);
color: navy;
text-align: center;
}
```

This was called in the html, and when I wrote the  &  everything would alternate.

Now I've tried:

```
div.colonial {
/* controls 1st cell of ev odd row */
tr:nth-child(odd) td:nth-child(3n+1) {
background-color: rgba(191, 178, 178, 0.44);
color: black;
text-align: center;
}
/* more tr commands  */
}
</div>
```

But it seems that using a  causes the tr:nth-child stuff to not work at all.

## How can I format my tables specifically to use the TD background color commans?

Here is the full css for one entry for odd cells

```
table {
width: 1000px;
height: auto;
border-collapse: separate;
border: 4px solid rgb(82,82,84);
border-spacing: 0.5rem;
vertical-align: top;
/* background-color: white; */
display:block;
}

/* controls 1st cell of ev odd row */
tr:nth-child(odd) td:nth-child(3n+1) {
background-color: rgba(41, 148, 87, 0.54);
color: black;
text-align: center;
}

/* controls 2nd cell of ev odd row */
tr:nth-child(odd) td:nth-child(3n+2) {
background-color: rgba(84, 146, 111, 0.50);
color: navy;
text-align: center;
}

/* controls 3rd cell of ev odd row */
tr:nth-child(odd) td:nth-child(3n+3) {
background-color: rgba(132, 167, 147, 0.50);
color: midnightblue;
text-align: center;
}
```

Here is a link to a page using the css with one table.   The 1st cell in each row is darker then cell 2 is lighter and cell 3 even lighter.  Then for the next row I have my other color sequence.    However I can't use this with two tables.
[table with differing cell color pattern](https://coinsandhistory.com/countries/Latam_Peru/Per_10.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If both tables share a common parent you can use `table:nth-child(2)` or simply add a class to your second table and use `table.myTableClass tr:nth-child(odd) etc..`

You might consider using `:nth-of-type` for your color striping, btw, it's a little cleaner/simpler.  [CSS Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/n/nth-of-type/)

Here is a jsfiddle where I used the code from your updated question to get the two tables to use different colors.  https://jsfiddle.net/wq6fc8p2/

**HTML**

```
<table class="t1">

</table>

<table class="t2">

</table>
```

---

**CSS**

```
table {
width: 1000px;
height: auto;
border-collapse: separate;
border: 4px solid rgb(82,82,84);
border-spacing: 0.5rem;
vertical-align: top;
/* background-color: white; */
display:block;
}

/* controls 1st cell of ev odd row */
.t1 tr:nth-child(odd) td:nth-child(3n+1) {
background-color: rgba(41, 148, 87, 0.54);
color: black;
text-align: center;
}

/* controls 2nd cell of ev odd row */
.t1 tr:nth-child(odd) td:nth-child(3n+2) {
background-color: rgba(84, 146, 111, 0.50);
color: navy;
text-align: center;
}

/* controls 3rd cell of ev odd row */
.t1 tr:nth-child(odd) td:nth-child(3n+3) {
background-color: rgba(132, 167, 147, 0.50);
color: midnightblue;
text-align: center;
}

/* controls 1st cell of ev odd row */
.t2 tr:nth-child(odd) td:nth-child(3n+1) {
background-color: rgba(22, 248, 187, 0.54);
color: black;
text-align: center;
}

/* controls 2nd cell of ev odd row */
.t2 tr:nth-child(odd) td:nth-child(3n+2) {
background-color: rgba(1, 199, 11, 0.50);
color: navy;
text-align: center;
}

/* controls 3rd cell of ev odd row */
.t2 tr:nth-child(odd) td:nth-child(3n+3) {
background-color: rgba(120, 150, 75, 0.50);
color: midnightblue;
text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work.  When I attempt to set the 2nd color it doesn't accept it.  Note that the tables are NOT one solid color but use alternating striped colors.

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't accept it?  Can you set up a snippet?   Why are you using `td:nth-child`?   You do realize that is only setting those colors on the 1st and 2nd cells of each odd row?   If you want the entire rows striped you shouldn't be using `td` anything.

Comment: @NicholasBourbaki updated my answer with an example of zebra striping using `nth-of-type`

Comment: Hi & Thanks,  I added to my original question since I can put code in there.  Look near the end, also it has a link.

Comment: @NicholasBourbaki OK, I have set up a fiddle (see updated answer for link) that shows it working with two tables.   Can you try it and let me know how it goes ?   Thanks

Comment: As soon as I figure out what a "fiddle" is I'll do it.  I think it's a test.  Working on it now.

Comment: @NicholasBourbaki jsut click the link to jsfiddle.net in my answer to go to the jsfiddle sandbox where i set up the working code.   (similar to the snippet feature on SO)

Comment: Okay, I'll do that.  However I just copied your css and can see it works!  Thanks a million.  Here's a link to my working test page.   https://coinsandhistory.com/testing/web_testing.html

Comment: Nice!  Glad I could help.  :)